# Changing texts and colors into images

Tags: javascript, html

I just wanted to make a roulette for fun and own experience and I'm far from being a JS master so..

Here is a ready code i found:

```
var colors = ["#B8D430", "#3AB745", "#029990", "#3501CB",
             "#2E2C75", "#673A7E", "#CC0071", "#F80120",
             "#F35B20", "#FB9A00", "#FFCC00", "#FEF200"];
var restaraunts = ["Wendy's", "McDonalds", "Chick-fil-a", "Five Guys",
                   "Gold Star", "La Mexicana", "Chipotle", "Tazza Mia",
                   "Panera", "Just Crepes", "Arby's", "Indian"];

var startAngle = 0;
var arc = Math.PI / 6;
var spinTimeout = null;

var spinArcStart = 10;
var spinTime = 0;
var spinTimeTotal = 0;

var ctx;

function drawRouletteWheel() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var outsideRadius = 200;
    var textRadius = 160;
    var insideRadius = 125;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);


    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;

    ctx.font = 'bold 12px Helvetica, Arial';

    for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
      ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
      ctx.arc(250, 250, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.save();
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
      ctx.shadowBlur    = 0;
      ctx.shadowColor   = "rgb(220,220,220)";
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius,
                    250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
      ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
      var text = restaraunts[i];
      ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
      ctx.restore();
    }

    //Arrow
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 13));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

function spin() {
  spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
  spinTime = 0;
  spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1000;
  rotateWheel();
}

function rotateWheel() {
  spinTime += 30;
  if(spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
    stopRotateWheel();
    return;
  }
  var spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal);
  startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
  drawRouletteWheel();
  spinTimeout = setTimeout('rotateWheel()', 30);
}

function stopRotateWheel() {
  clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
  var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
  var arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
  var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.font = 'bold 30px Helvetica, Arial';
  var text = "You won\n" + restaraunts[index]
  ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
  ctx.restore();
}

function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
  var ts = (t/=d)*t;
  var tc = ts*t;
  return b+c*(tc + -3*ts + 3*t);
}

drawRouletteWheel();
```

I'm wondering how can i change the background colors to background images and to add images to `restaraunts`, and also the `\n` signs are not making new lines on `var text = "You won\n" + restaraunts[index]`.

I know these are really basic questions but again - I'm not so much familiar with JS so if someone could help it can be cool ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use setSyle to set the backround-image property instead of background-color, and use <br /> instead of \n for new lines.

Update: Again, the text is drawn on a canvas. To get a new line, you could do something like this, since \n doesn't seem to do much:

```
ctx.fillText("You won!", -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 12);
```

Update 2: I found how to draw images to the canvas, and there are settings to get a rectangular portion of the image, but I don't know how to mask an image with a polygon shape that isn't a rectangle yet:

```
function drawImage() {
    var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img=new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    };
    img.src="panera.jpg";
}
```

Comment: 1) I don't see background-color anywhere, can you please give me a code example? 2) you didn't wrote anything after "and use..." and use what?

Comment: Oh shoot it just interpreted it as html. Use the BR tag for line breaks in html. I'll try to look through your code in depth to find the place that sets the background colors.

Comment: Well it looks like it is drawing shapes on a canvas with a background color set with fillStyle - I haven't been able to turn up any information about using fillStyle with an image, but I'll keep looking around as that seems like a great feature to be able to use.

Comment: Thanks buddy! (and the <br/> doesn't work as well i have already tried) but it is not so important.

Comment: Added in new line and image code, perhaps you should try finding a more in depth reference to the Canvas object and it's features to try and work out a polygon shape to mask an image?

Comment: Looks like the ctx.clip function would be something you could use

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is only javascript. You need to have some html and css to show content and to style it. When you have html you can change background of html element, `<div class="myClass"></div>` for example with this css:

```
.myClass
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

or to have image as background:

```
.myClass
{
    background-image:url('paper.gif');
}
```

and yes, use `<br/>` as a line break in browsers.

Comment: It works with HTML5 (drawing the shapes) so I'm not sure it will work here.

Comment: Yeah the drawing shapes are just drawn on the canvas, so they aren't HTML elements.